# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in /home/....../..../

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, many-to-many

I've these tables `users`,`tasks`,`roles`,`permissions` & a pivot table `permissions_roles`.

roles:

1. `role_id`: auto_increament
2. `role_name`: admin/standard

permissions:

1. `permission_id`: auto_increament
2. `permission_name`: create/edit/delete

Pivot table: permissions_roles

1. `p_id(FOREIGN KEY (r_id) REFERENCES roles(role_id))`
2. `r_id(FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES permissions(permission_id))`

But when I'm trying to insert values into the pivot table, by writing this code:

```
function roles($role_name){
        mysqli_query($this->connect,"INSERT INTO roles ( role_name ) VALUES ('$role_name')");
        SET @r_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    }
```

Then I'm getting this error:

Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '@' in /home/directory/project_folder/users.php
```

I need to assign multiple permissions for each roles. Please help.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: `SET @r_id =` is not a php comment

Comment: You're mixing SQL and PHP together. `SET @r_Id` is a sql piece of code that you've got in the php section. Do you mean to use `$r_id = $this->connect->insert_id;` ? _edited insert call - thanks Riggs :P_

Comment: `$r_id = $this->connect->insert_id;`